# how to add filter functions to a Firebase reference after it was created

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

For some reason these 2 examples don't return the same value.

**Example 1**

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('fruits').orderByChild('name').equalTo('Mango')
ref.once('value',function(snapshot){
    console.log(snapshot.val())
})
```

Returns:

```
{
    "mango":{"name":"Mango"}
}
```

**Example 2**

```
var ref2 = firebase.database().ref('fruits')
ref2.orderByChild('name').equalTo('Mango')
ref2.once('value',function(snapshot){
    console.log(snapshot.val())
})
```

Returns:

```
{
    "apple":{"name":"Apple"},
    "banana":{"name":"Banana"},
    "mango":{"name":"Mango"},
    "strawberry":{"name":"Strawberry"}
}
```

The difference in example 2 is that the filtering functions are applied to the reference **after** it was created, which in principle should be similar to method chaining.

If this isn't a bug, how can these filter functions be applied **after** the reference was created?

[You can see this running in this JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b3a62avs/2/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling `orderByChild()`, `equalTo()` or one of the other ordering/filtering methods on a reference returns a new object. So example 2 should be:

```
var ref2 = firebase.database().ref('fruits')
var query = ref2.orderByChild('name').equalTo('Mango')
query.once('value',function(snapshot){
    console.log(snapshot.val())
})
```